When does the image of a point lie in the relative interior of a convex set?
Suppose we have a continuous function $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that is injective and such that the closure of the image of $F$, $\overline{F(\mathbb{R}^n)} \subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ is a bounded convex set.
Is it true that $F(0)$ belongs to the interior of $\overline{F(\mathbb{R}^n)}$?
Thanks for any help in advance.

What are your thoughts on it?
